# How does new wrapper work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In the context of underscore.js:

```
// Create a safe reference to the Underscore object for use below.
   var _ = function(obj) { return new wrapper(obj); };
```

Simply put, what does this function return?

Comment: it returns a new instance of the wrapper type. Read more about javascript's object model here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Comment: Which is an object oriented bit of code, based on some other javascript you would likely have somewhere. That has the wrapper object/class in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/jashkenas/underscore/06c773b06e53ec9a089f17c18852098cb1e25c66/docs/underscore.html#section-9) is a wrapper function for the [`wrapper` constructor](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/jashkenas/underscore/06c773b06e53ec9a089f17c18852098cb1e25c66/docs/underscore.html#section-131) to allow you using underscore without the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). Calling underscore will always return a new `wrapper` instance.

---

Btw, the `wrapper` function has been removed in [this commit](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/6587a30099fd283abd0e5b2b9918f1ec88a0dd6a#diff-1). The `_` function itself is the constructor now, see [Understanding the declaration of the underscore in _.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660955/understanding-the-declaration-of-the-underscore-in-js) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

simply put, it's a constructor for 'wrapper' to make things a big easier for you

```
// this allows you to do things such as:
var a = _({/*object*/});

// rether than something like:
var a = new wrapper({/*object*/});
```

I think in the since of underscore.js it's to keep your coding tiddy and simple :)