# this in function "_" from underscore.js

Tags: javascript, constructor, underscore.js

Im trying to work out underscore.js code and i have problem at the start.
This snippet is described as 'Create a safe reference to the Underscore object for use below.'

```
 var _ = function(obj) {
   if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
   if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
   this._wrapped = obj;
 };
```

I don't get it. Is that a simple function or constructor? At the first sight it has:

```
this._wrapped = obj;
```

So it is constructor but it has two 'ifs' with return, so is that a constructor when if's get false and function when one of ifs get true value ?

And the other questions:

```
if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
```

what is 'this' here ? And why is that provede safety. If that if get true is that creating object of itself? Is that something like recursion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does new wrapper work in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836186/how-does-new-wrapper-work-in-javascript)

Comment: It's both - a constructor function :-)

Comment: @raina77ow: That question seems to be about an older version of the underscore code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript functions are used as constructor. Any function can is used as constructor when you use the `new` operator. Taking a simple `sum` function for example:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var x = new sum(10, 2);

console.log(x); // object
console.log(x instanceof sum); // true;
```

And here we get to the second part: how we can actually understand if a `function` is called as constructor, or not? Using the line `this instanceof` you mentioned above. Basically:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    if (this instanceof sum) {
        this.result = a + b;
    } else {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

If a function is called as constructor, the contextual object `this` points to the new object just created.

This technique is also used to have a `new`-free syntax in some library, in a similar way the code you posted does, so that `new` is optional:

```
var panel = Panel();
```

Internally, they just check `this`:

```
function Panel() {
    if (this instanceof Panel) {
        return this; // `new` operator was used
    } else {
        return new Panel(); // called without `new`, so we create a new object
    }
}
```