# Understanding the declaration of the underscore in _.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is from the beginning of the [annotated source of _.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html). Try though I may, my JavaScript abilities are not at a high enough level to understand what's going on here. I'm hoping someone can give a real step by step explanation. I really have literally *no idea* what the code below does besides somehow setting up the _ for use, despite that I understand each individual expression.

```
 var _ = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
  };

  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
      exports = module.exports = _;
    }
    exports._ = _;
  } else {
    root._ = _;
  }
```

Comment: My Question, why does it matter what it does?

Comment: ....trying to learn and understand advanced coding techniques?

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Well first off, you need to know what `instanceof` does. The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor. More about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: Patterns that check context before exposing are called [universal module definitions](https://github.com/umdjs/umd). [See here too.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9009810/770127)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var _ = function(obj) {
    // Either serve as the identity function on `_` instances,
    // ... or instantiate a new `_` object for other input.

    // If an `_` instance was passed, return it.
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    // If someone called `_(...)`, rather than `new _(...)`,
    // ... return `new _(...)` to instantiate an instance.
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);

    // If we are instantiating a new `_` object with an underlying,
    // ... object, set that object to the `_wrapped` property.
    this._wrapped = obj;
};

// If there is an exports value (for modularity)...
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    // If we're in Node.js with module.exports...
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        // Set the export to `_`
        exports = module.exports = _;
    }
    // Export `_` as `_`
    exports._ = _;
} else {
    // Otherwise, set `_` on the global object, as set at the beginning
    // ... via `(function(){ var root = this; /* ... */ }())`
    root._ = _;
}
```

Comment: Afaik `root` is the global scope.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, wasn't familiar with the underscore source.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the lower snippet is quite unrelated. Basically it's exporting the `_` from the closure to the global scope, or using a [module definition system](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules) if available. No great deal, and nothing to care about if you don't use modules.

The `_` function shouldn't be that hard to understand. You need to know

- [What is the underscore function for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16378628/1048572)
- What does the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) do?
- How does the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) work?

So what it does:

1. If the argument is an Underscore instance, return it unchanged.
2. If the function is not called as a constructor (when the `this` context is not an Underscore instance) then do so and return that
3. Else wrap the argument in the current instance

Comment: Sometimes I wish SO had an option to merge answers.

Comment: There are wiki answers… But why, this way you can upvote both of them? :-)